# Pointer to Pointer of Array. Deference. Alternative Code Fragments

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dereference

I am a novice programmer, and I am trying to understand this code a little better. I've done some reading, and I *think* what I have deduced is correct.

```
homekit_service_t* services[5]; 
homekit_service_t** s = services;
```

[image]

`services[]` is an array of `homekit_service_t` **pointers**. `services` is a pointer to `&services[0]`. `s` is a pointer to `&services[0]` - its value is the address of `services[0]`. Therefore, you could also write it as.

```
homekit_service_t* s = &services[0];
```

Further down, it starts doing this.

```
*(s++) = //address return from calloc
```

So it *deferences* `s`; it goes to the address stored in `s` (say, `#2000` in my picture), and then stores the value returned by `calloc` into that location

So, you could write this instead?

```
i = 0; 
services[i] = //address return from calloc 
i++;
```

Is that correct?

Comment: `&services[0]` has the same type as `services`, so `homekit_service_t* s = &services[0];` is not correct. Your compiler will inform you of that fact when you try to compile that code.

Comment: `services`  is not a pointer, it is an array. It *decays* to a pointer in most but not all contexts. `services[]` is not an entity at all.